# How to get the code to display amount of the discount & the total amount of the purchase after the discount & including the giftwrapping if needed

Tags: python

> baseballs cost $1.99 each

> Develop a Python program that prompts the user to enter the number of baseballs purchased
> In addition the program should ask the user if they want giftwrapping and if so add another $2.00 to the order.
>
> I simply want my output to prompt the amount of the discount
> (if any) and the total amount of the purchase after the discount and
> including the giftwrapping if needed. But I don't know what code is needed to display that output? so I need someone to show me what code it is?

```
Quantity  Discount
 0 - 9        0%
 10 - 50      5%
 51 or more   10%

baseballs = int(input("Enter the number of baseballs purchased: "))
if(baseballs>0):
    if baseballs<=9:
       disc = baseballs*0.00
    elif baseballs<=50:
       disc = baseballs*0.05
    elif baseballs>=51:
        disc=baseballs*0.10
        print("Discount : ",disc)
gift_wrapping = input("Do you want gift wrapping?: ")
print(baseballs + " " + "baseballs purchased" )
print(gift_wrapping)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe? Not 100% sure what you're asking:

Do let me know if you want comments on the code.

```py
price = 1.99
baseballs = int(input("Enter the number of baseballs purchased: "))
if(baseballs>0):
    if 0 <= baseballs <= 9:
       disc = baseballs*0.00
    elif 9 <= baseballs <= 50:
       disc = baseballs*0.05
    elif baseballs <= 51:
        disc=baseballs*0.10
        print("Discount : ",disc)
gift_wrapping = input("Do you want gift wrapping?: ")

if gift_wrapping == "yes" or "y" or "Yes":
    total = (baseballs * price) - disc + 2
else:
    total = (baseballs * price) - disc

print(str(baseballs) + " " + "baseballs purchased" )

if disc != 0:
    total_disc = total-(baseballs*price)
    print("Discount: "+str(total_disc))

print("Total price "+str(total))
```